# Tableau API for Python, Get Parameter Value -- JS's .getParametersAsync() Equivalent for Python

Tags: python, tableau-api

I want to extract a workbook's currently set parameter values.

I've found reference of the desired request, as someone uses it in JS, but I can't find it anywhere in the REST API documentation, nor the documentation for `tableau-api-lib` nor `tableauserverclient`. [Tableau API: Get parameter value](https://community.tableau.com/s/question/0D54T00000C5xRiSAJ/tableau-api-get-parameter-value)

I can query workbooks just fine using either of the above referenced libraries, but is there a method I'm missing somewhere to get the parameter values?

Ideally I'd like to be able to modify them before a query, but getting what they're currently set at would be a nice start.

Javascript equivalent:

```js
paramObjs = currentViz.getWorkbook().getParametersAsync();
    paramObjs.then(function(paramObjs) {
        for (var i = 0; i < paramObjs.length; i++) {
            try {
                var name = paramObjs[i].getName();
                var value = paramObjs[i].getCurrentValue();
                params[name] = value.value;
            } catch (e) { }
        }
    });
```

Comment: What do the parameters include?

Comment: Parameters are just singular values for the Dashboard that can be set. They're either Floats, Integers, Strings, Booleans, Dates, or Date & Times. [More here](https://help.tableau.com/current/pro/desktop/en-us/parameters_create.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what it looks like, this task can not be done using Python.

1. The [Workbook](https://tableau.github.io/server-client-python/docs/api-ref#workbooks) class here does not have any attributes/methods to get parameters
2. Tableau's REST API [reference](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref_workbooks_and_views.htm#query_workbook) has no method/endpoint for that
3. Other API's like the [Metadata](https://help.tableau.com/current/api/rest_api/en-us/REST/rest_api_ref_metadata.htm) and Hyper APIs have no connection/correlation  with the task
4. A list of all Tableau packages/libraries is given [here](https://tableau.github.io/). Going through all Python libraries, there wasn't any method to fetch the parameters.

In JavaScript, they are actually creating visualizations, which allows them to query the visualization itself (`currentViz.getWorkbook()`). The same isn't applicable for Python I guess, which explains the missing support/APIs.

Comment: The bit about why JavaScript is different makes sense, I was hoping for the possibility of wrapping the JavaScript function, even if I had to do it myself, but couldn't wrap my head around what it was actually doing without context.